# Aligning file output with "\t"

Tags: perl

I have an assignment that requires me to print out some sorted lists and delimit the fields by '\t'.  I've finished the assignment but I cannot seem to get all the fields to line up with just the tab character.  Some of the output is below, names that are over a certain length break the fields.  How can I still use '\t' and get everything aligned by only that much space?

```
open(DOB, ">dob.txt") || die "cannot open $!";

# Output name and DOB, sorted by month
foreach my $key (sort {$month{$a} <=> $month{$b}} keys %month)  
{ 
    my @fullName = split(/ /, $namelist{$key});
    print DOB "$fullName[1], $fullName[0]\t$doblist{$key}\n";
}
close(DOB);
```

Current output:

```
Santiago, Jose   1/5/58
Pinhead, Zippy   1/1/67
Neal, Jesse      2/3/36
Gutierrez, Paco  2/28/53
Sailor, Popeye   3/19/35
Corder, Norma    3/28/45
Kirstin, Lesley  4/22/62
Fardbarkle, Fred             4/12/23
```

Comment: Is this to be *human* readable (you might want to look at the old school [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) and write for alignment of text in reports), or *computer* readable (in which case multiple tabs may confuse the field separator)?

Comment: Human, just for an assignment really.  It specifies separating fields by '\t'.

Comment: I would then look to follow *exactly* the specification and use only a single tab. Putting two tabs in place would indicate that there is another field on some rows.  Tabs aren't meant for visual alignment (thats spaces) in part because the tab width on different views can be different.  Load it into a word processor, and they are 1/2".  Load it into a spread sheet and they are different columns, load it into vi and they are 8 spaces (unless you set them to 4).  Tabs separate fields and thats what is being asked.  Use one tab, and one tab only for your assignment.

Comment: True, I just can't get a single tab to line everything up. Ahh, missed the last half of your comment...ok will do thanks

Comment: You can... just open your editor and set the tab width to 16 characters.  In the meantime (for personal growth), if you want to play with aligning text output for reports, look at `format` in perl. It has some rather neat features (`@|||` for center align, `@<<<` for left align, `@>>>` for right align, and `@###.##` for decimal point alignment... headers and footers... etc.  Very nice for text only report generation).

Comment: (The documentation on perl `format` - [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) if you want to look into that... its rather 'old' (part of the original goal of perl was report generation) and very powerful for templateing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how many spaces are equivalent to a tab. Then you can work out how many tabs are covered by each entry.

If tabs take 4 spaces then the following code works:

```
$TAB_SPACE = 4;
$NUM_TABS  = 4;
foreach my $key (sort {$month{$a} <=> $month{$b}} keys %month) {
    my @fullName = split(/ /, $namelist{$key});
    my $name = "$fullName[1], $fullName[0]";

    # This rounds down, but that just means you need a partial tab
    my $covered_tabs = int(length($name) / $TAB_SPACE);

    print $name . ("\t" x ($NUM_TABS - $covered_tabs)) . $doblist{$key}\n";
}
```

You need to know how many tabs to pad out to, but you could work that out in a very similar way to actually printing the lines.

Comment: But then the fields are no longer delimited by tabs as the teacher requested. The teacher's request and the OP's request are in conflict.

Comment: The difference is between delimiting and aligning. If it must be delimited then only a single tab is required and it will just look rubbish.

Comment: It just says, 'separated by tab '\t'.

Comment: If this does not work, check `$TAB_SPACE` variable. In my case I had to set it to `8`.